# How to handle rotation of selection rectangle that can be resized?

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, transform, rotatetransform

Im my application the user can select areas of an image.
The user drags a rectangular area in a `Canvas`. It looks like the following:

[image: Rectangle selection area]

The circle (`Ellipse`) on top of the selection area, is a handle to rotate the area. See picture below:

[image]

When the selection area is *not* rotated, and the user uses the square shaped handles to resize the area, it works.
But when the user rotates the selection area using the ellipse, and then uses a square handle to resize the area, it resizes in both opposite directions (in context of the rotated coordinate system).

My element structure is as follows:

```
Canvas
+--- Image (covers whole canvas)
+--- Canvas (Background white with opacity as shown in images above, and contains the elements to draw the 
           selection area. I'll call this the 'area canvas')
    +--- Rectangle (left handle)
    +--- Rectangle (top handle)
    +--- Rectangle (right handle)
    +--- Rectangle (bottom handle)
    +--- Ellipse (rotation handle)
```

I do the rotation using a `RotateTransform`. The transform is applied the **Canvas of the selection area**.
The *RenderTransformOrigin* of the canvas is (0.5, 0.5). So the Canvas will always be rotated around it's center.

Imagine the area is rotated for say 10 degrees clockwise. Then you resize it using the handle at the right. Now the area should only expand to the right side. In other words: only 2 corners of the area canvas should be moving,
What happens how, is that the left side of the area also moves. So also the corners at the left side move (to the left).
I think this is caused by the fact that the change of the width/height of the area canvas also changes the center point.
But how to fix it? The behaviour of the selection area should be exactly the same as a selected element in programs like MS Word.

**Link to Github repository containing the relevant code:** https://github.com/websitetest/selection

Comment: it will be interesting to have the whole coding to help you.....not only an explanation. xaml code and c# code. If you could share your project in shared drive or other...

Comment: I edit my answer and added a Github link.

Comment: why you dont change the render transform origin to (0, 0) when you resize by right or (1,0) when you resize by left.. in fact you select opposite origin point to the resized side?

Comment: As far as I know, I never change the transform origin. It's always (0.5, 0.5)

Comment: so to investigate more, and do some test , could you put your solution on github and not just some programs?

Comment: I added a Solution file to the Github repository. Please check if it runs on your side. The solution must be enough to find the problem about my transformation issue. Let me know if you still need more.

Comment: ok i see the problem with the selection rotated moving when the resizing is in action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add a translation which cancels the move of the center of canvas after a rotation: so i have done some modification to you method UpdateResizeArea (mathematic solution)

```
    private void UpdateResizeArea(Point currentMousePoint)
    {
           :
           :
        switch (_activeResizeAreaSide)
        {
            case SelectionArea.ResizeSide.LEFT:
                {
                    _activeResizeArea.OffsetX = _activeResizeAreaXbeforeStart + deltaX;
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaWidth = _activeResizeAreaWidthbeforeStart - deltaX;
                    var tg = new TransformGroup();
                    var rad = _activeResizeArea.Rotation * Math.PI / 180;
                    var cx = _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().X - _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.X;
                    var cy = _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().Y - _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.Y;

                    var tx = cx * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * 2d + cy * Math.Sin(rad);
                    var ty = cx * Math.Sin(rad) - cy * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * 2d;

                    var t = new TranslateTransform(-tx, ty);

                    tg.Children.Add(_activeResizeArea.RotateTransform);
                    tg.Children.Add(t);

                    _activeResizeArea.AreaCanvas.RenderTransform = tg;
                }
                break;
            case SelectionArea.ResizeSide.TOP:
                {
                    _activeResizeArea.OffsetY = _activeResizeAreaYbeforeStart + deltaY;
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaHeight = _activeResizeAreaHeightbeforeStart - deltaY;

                    var tg = new TransformGroup();
                    var rad = _activeResizeArea.Rotation * Math.PI / 180;

                    var cx = _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().X - _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.X;
                    var cy = _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().Y - _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.Y;

                    var tx = cy * Math.Sin(rad) + cx * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * 2d;
                    var ty = cy * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * 2d - cx * Math.Sin(rad);

                    var t = new TranslateTransform(-tx, -ty);

                    tg.Children.Add(_activeResizeArea.RotateTransform);
                    tg.Children.Add(t);
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaCanvas.RenderTransform = tg;
                }
                break;
            case SelectionArea.ResizeSide.RIGHT:
                {
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaWidth = _activeResizeAreaWidthbeforeStart + deltaX;

                    var tg = new TransformGroup();
                    var rad = _activeResizeArea.Rotation * Math.PI / 180;
                    var cx = _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().X - _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.X;
                    var cy = _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().Y - _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.Y;

                    var tx = cx * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * 2d + cy * Math.Sin(rad);
                    var ty = cx * Math.Sin(rad) - cy * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * 2d;

                    var t = new TranslateTransform(-tx, ty);

                    tg.Children.Add(_activeResizeArea.RotateTransform);
                    tg.Children.Add(t);
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaCanvas.RenderTransform = tg;
                }
                break;
            case SelectionArea.ResizeSide.BOTTOM:
                {
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaHeight = _activeResizeAreaHeightbeforeStart + deltaY;

                    var tg = new TransformGroup();
                    var rad = _activeResizeArea.Rotation * Math.PI / 180;

                    var cx = _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().X - _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.X;
                    var cy = _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().Y - _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.Y;

                    var tx = cy * Math.Sin(rad) + cx * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * 2d;
                    var ty = cy * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * Math.Sin(rad / 2d) * 2d - cx * Math.Sin(rad);

                    var t = new TranslateTransform(-tx, -ty);

                    tg.Children.Add(_activeResizeArea.RotateTransform);
                    tg.Children.Add(t);
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaCanvas.RenderTransform = tg;
                }
                break;
        }
```

you could adapt the solution to your project.. because i have just added some lines of coding without changing the logic of your program

**__________________________________________________________________________________**

Another solution (without math calculus) is to precalculate the difference betwwen the position of one point of canvas with the initial Center of rotation and the new position of same point with the new center:

```
        switch (_activeResizeAreaSide)
        {
            case SelectionArea.ResizeSide.LEFT:
                {
                    _activeResizeArea.OffsetX = _activeResizeAreaXbeforeStart + deltaX;
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaWidth = _activeResizeAreaWidthbeforeStart - deltaX;

                    var ir = new RotateTransform(_activeResizeArea.Rotation, _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.X, _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.Y);
                    var fr = new RotateTransform(_activeResizeArea.Rotation, _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().X, _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().Y);
                    var ip = ir.Transform(new Point(_activeResizeArea.OffsetX, _activeResizeArea.OffsetY));
                    var fp = fr.Transform(new Point(_activeResizeArea.OffsetX, _activeResizeArea.OffsetY));

                    var tg = new TransformGroup();

                    var txx = ip.X - fp.X;
                    var tyy = ip.Y - fp.Y;

                    var t = new TranslateTransform(txx, tyy);

                    tg.Children.Add(_activeResizeArea.RotateTransform);
                    tg.Children.Add(t);

                    _activeResizeArea.AreaCanvas.RenderTransform = tg;
                }
                break;
            case SelectionArea.ResizeSide.TOP:
                {
                    _activeResizeArea.OffsetY = _activeResizeAreaYbeforeStart + deltaY;
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaHeight = _activeResizeAreaHeightbeforeStart - deltaY;

                    var ir = new RotateTransform(_activeResizeArea.Rotation, _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.X, _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.Y);
                    var fr = new RotateTransform(_activeResizeArea.Rotation, _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().X, _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().Y);
                    var ip = ir.Transform(new Point(_activeResizeArea.OffsetX, _activeResizeArea.OffsetY));
                    var fp = fr.Transform(new Point(_activeResizeArea.OffsetX, _activeResizeArea.OffsetY));

                    var tg = new TransformGroup();

                    var txx = ip.X - fp.X;
                    var tyy = ip.Y - fp.Y;

                    var t = new TranslateTransform(txx, tyy);

                    tg.Children.Add(_activeResizeArea.RotateTransform);
                    tg.Children.Add(t);
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaCanvas.RenderTransform = tg;
                }
                break;
            case SelectionArea.ResizeSide.RIGHT:
                {
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaWidth = _activeResizeAreaWidthbeforeStart + deltaX;

                    var ir = new RotateTransform(_activeResizeArea.Rotation, _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.X, _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.Y);
                    var fr = new RotateTransform(_activeResizeArea.Rotation, _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().X, _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().Y);
                    var ip = ir.Transform(new Point(_activeResizeArea.OffsetX, _activeResizeArea.OffsetY));
                    var fp = fr.Transform(new Point(_activeResizeArea.OffsetX, _activeResizeArea.OffsetY));

                    var tg = new TransformGroup();

                    var txx = ip.X - fp.X;
                    var tyy = ip.Y - fp.Y;

                    var t = new TranslateTransform(txx, tyy);

                    tg.Children.Add(_activeResizeArea.RotateTransform);
                    tg.Children.Add(t);
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaCanvas.RenderTransform = tg;
                }
                break;
            case SelectionArea.ResizeSide.BOTTOM:
                {
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaHeight = _activeResizeAreaHeightbeforeStart + deltaY;

                    var ir = new RotateTransform(_activeResizeArea.Rotation, _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.X, _activeRotateAreaCenterPointBeforeStart.Y);
                    var fr = new RotateTransform(_activeResizeArea.Rotation, _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().X, _activeResizeArea.CalculateCenterPoint().Y);
                    var ip = ir.Transform(new Point(_activeResizeArea.OffsetX, _activeResizeArea.OffsetY));
                    var fp = fr.Transform(new Point(_activeResizeArea.OffsetX, _activeResizeArea.OffsetY));

                    var tg = new TransformGroup();

                    var txx = ip.X - fp.X;
                    var tyy = ip.Y - fp.Y;

                    var t = new TranslateTransform(txx, tyy);

                    tg.Children.Add(_activeResizeArea.RotateTransform);
                    tg.Children.Add(t);
                    _activeResizeArea.AreaCanvas.RenderTransform = tg;
                }
                break;
        }
```

Result:

[image: Result]